# No view found for id "bla bla bla" for grammatically created framlayout

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout, dynamiclayout

I am creating a framelayout pro-grammatically. Then I create fragment pro-grammatically..Then I want to add the fragment to the framelayout.. this process is happens every time when I click the button. For the framelayout id and fragment tag I created a integer increment variable("id" is initiated as to "0" when beginning)..

When very time I click the button new framelayout with new id create, create fragment with new tag, fragement is added to that framelayout...And contentious overlapping views..

Here below my code,

```
public void add_tab(View view)
{
    id++;
    String b = String.valueOf(id);
    tab_frame = new FrameLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    tab_frame.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    tab_frame.setId (id);


    FragmentManager fragment_manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager ();                         // fragment manager for dealing with fragments
    frag_one frag_one_obj = new frag_one();                                                   // creating a onj of fragment "frag_one"
    FragmentTransaction fr_transaction = fragment_manager1.beginTransaction ();
    fr_transaction.add (tab_frame.getId (),frag_one_obj,b);
    fr_transaction.addToBackStack ("Fragment Add");
    fr_transaction.commit ();
    frag_one_obj.setArguments (bundle);
    tab_frame.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
}
```

When I debug I am getting this error in logcat,

```
No view found for id 0x1 (unknown) for fragment frag_one{42bb0cc8 (d45032ae-5aa4-485f-87a6-da20f3d5ce1f) id=0x1 1}
```

Idon't know why that happens..I am already creating framelayout and assign a id for that..But this error tells there is no view assgned to this perticular id, so Fragment can't be added..

Pls help me..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the created `FrameLayout` as child of your hosting view. Otherwise it is attached no where. That's why the view is not being find with it's id.

Comment: I am new to android studio..How can I do this? The created frame should be in activity_main.xml file's main "ConstraintLayout"

Comment: The created frame should be in activity_main.xml file's main "ConstraintLayout" So I did this way,  Typecasted the "ConstraintLayout" to a new ConstraintLayout type object. then I added created frame to that as "constraintLayout.addView (tab_frame);" ..Then It worked..  Thanks lot..